# Firebase ui 3.1.0 (Firebaselistadapter) No setter/field for mc_name found on class

Tags: android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I've tried my code in normal activity both images and text show. **in fragment only image showing but the text is not showing** (in both normal and fragment activity I've used same xml layout). I'm using firebaselistadpter for gridview and it works fine. I also tried using it with listview in fragment still images only showing **but no text showing.** (there is no Error message).

1- my java activity:

```
public class R_MainCat extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<Sub_Category_Data> adapter;
    private TextView mc_name;
    private ImageView url;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gridview, container, false);

        rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        myRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Main_Category");
        Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);


     FirebaseListOptions<Sub_Category_Data> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Sub_Category_Data>()
                .setQuery(myRef, Sub_Category_Data.class).setLayout(R.layout.gridview_icon).build();

        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Sub_Category_Data>(options) {

            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Sub_Category_Data model, int position) {
                mc_name = v.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);
                url = v.findViewById(R.id.img);
                mc_name.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(model.getUrl()).into(url);
            }
        };
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
                switch(i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        R_DairyProds f1 = new R_DairyProds();
                        FragmentTransaction fragTransaction1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragTransaction1.replace(R.id.container_view,f1 );
                        fragTransaction1.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragTransaction1.commit();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        R_Bakery f2 = new R_Bakery();
                        FragmentTransaction fragTransaction2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragTransaction2.replace(R.id.container_view,f2 );
                        fragTransaction2.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragTransaction2.commit();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        R_Grocery f3 = new R_Grocery();
                        FragmentTransaction fT3 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fT3.replace(R.id.container_view,f3);
                        fT3.addToBackStack(null);
                        fT3.commit();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        R_FruitsNVegs f4 = new R_FruitsNVegs();
                        FragmentTransaction fT4 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fT4.replace(R.id.container_view,f4);
                        fT4.addToBackStack(null);
                        fT4.commit();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        R_CleanNWash f5 = new R_CleanNWash();
                        FragmentTransaction fT5 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fT5.replace(R.id.container_view,f5);
                        fT5.addToBackStack(null);
                        fT5.commit();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;

    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

2-my xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
            <me.grantland.widget.AutofitLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img"
                >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cat_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="hello_world"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            </me.grantland.widget.AutofitLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

3- my Data model java:

```
public class Sub_Category_Data {

    private  String mc_name;
    private  String url;

    public Sub_Category_Data() {
    }

 public void setName(String mc_name) {
        this.mc_name = mc_name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return mc_name;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

4- snapshot of the output:
text suppose to be showing under the image.

[Output in fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znVne.png)

I want my fragment to show the text data same as what is showing in this image

[Output I've tested in normal Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqhz5.png)

5- database snapshot:
[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmLVQ.png)

does anyone have any clue? or have faced this issue before? because I'm lost since there is no error showing besides the fact it works fine in normal activity but text is not showing in the fragment. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking over and over I noticed this in logcat 
**"No setter/field for mc_name found on class"**

I've fixed the problem. It was in the *model class* **getName()** and **SetName()** methods I **changed them to same name as the child key name in my firebase** you can see picture of the database in the question above. so the new methods are getMc_name() and setMc_name().

```
public class Sub_Category_Data {

    private  String mc_name;
    private  String url;

    public Sub_Category_Data() {
    }

    public String getMc_name() {
        return mc_name;
    }

    public void setMc_name(String mc_name) {
        this.mc_name = mc_name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

the output [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v10wQ.png)